# Method call with nullable and not nullable Collection

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

Is it possible in Kotlin to write a function which can be called with nullable and not nullable collections? I think about something like this:

```
fun <C: MutableCollection<out String>> f(c: C): C {
    // ...
}
```

Not that I need to write it like this because I have a return value of type `C`. Also note the `out` keyword but even with it I can't call `f(mutableListOf<String?>)` but `f(mutableListOf<String>)` works fine. What do I have to change here or isn't that possible in Kotlin? With arrays this would work just fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun <C: MutableCollection<out String?>> f(c: C): C {
    return c;
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(f(mutableListOf("hello")))
    println(f(mutableListOf<String?>(null)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Can you please explain why the `?` is the important thing here? When using arrays `Array<out T>` works as well as `Array<out T?>`

Comment: With Array, it wouldn't compile, because "upper bound of a type parameter cannot be an array". The ? is important because... you want to be able to pass a mutable collection of nullable strings, and MutableCollection<out String> is a collection of non-nullable strings.

Comment: @Cilenco: `out` very roughly means 'or a subtype'.  And a nullable type like `String?` is a supertype of its non-nullable base type `String`.  That's why it needs the `?`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing things up here (referring to your comment)... `Collection<out T>` would work the same way as `Array<out T>`. In that case `T` could by anything (i.e. `T : Any?`)... as soon as you set the `T` to `String`, which you are basically doing with your `C`, then you must use a non-nullable type...

While the short answer is to just add `?` to the generic type `C`, i.e. using `fun <C: MutableCollection<out String?>> f(c: C):C` here are some more examples which may help to better understand how that all plays together:

```
// your variant:
fun <C : MutableCollection<out String>> f1(c: C): C = TODO()
// given type must be non-nullable; returned one therefore contains too only non-nullable types

// your variant with just another generic type
fun <T : String, C : MutableCollection<out T>> f2(c: C): C = TODO()
// you have now your "out T", but it still accepts only non-nullable types (now it is probably just more visible as it is in front)

// previous variant adapted to allow nullable types:
fun <T : String?, C : MutableCollection<out T>> f3(c: C): C = TODO()
```

Finally the solution to your problem can be one of the following (depending what you really require):

```
fun <T : String?> f4a(c: MutableCollection<out T>): MutableCollection<out T> = TODO()
fun <C : MutableCollection<out String?>> f4b(c: C): C = TODO()
```